# How to support different type in indexable interface?

Tags: typescript

There has an example in Typescript Document.

```
interface NumberDictionary {
    [index: string]: number;
    length: number;    // ok, length is a number
    name: string;      // error, the type of 'name' is not a subtype of the indexer
}
```

I'm understand why it's incorrect. 
But sometimes I really want a object with `name: string`, `length: number` type. And others indexs is `number`. How to do write interface to match follow object?

```
{
  name: 'Bill',
  length: 123,
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  // .... blahblah
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define such a type using intersection types, but you will need to use `Object.assign` to initialize it, an object literal will not be able to satify bot the index and `name`:

```
type NumberDictionary = { [index: string]: number; } & {
    length: number;
    name: string;
}

var dd: NumberDictionary = Object.assign({
    name: 'Bill',
    length: 123
}, {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
});
let fc = dd["foo"] // number
let dName = dd.name; //string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use intersection types.

```
type NumberDictionary = {
    [index: string]: number
} & {
    length: number,
    name: string,
}
```